# Maven checkstyle error : Expected @param tag for '<T>'

Tags: java, maven, generics, javadoc, checkstyle

I have following method with generic types, but when I run maven checkstyle(maven-checkstyle-plugin, 2.121) it 
kept gives me `Expected @param tag for '<T>'` error message during maven build. How do I get over with this?

```
/**
 * Read in specified type of object from request body.
 * @param request The HttpServletRequest
 * @param expected The expected type T
 * @return <T> specified type of object
 */
public <T extends Object> T getExpectedValue(
    final HttpServletRequest request, final Class<T> expected)
```

I used following to turn generic param tag off, but it didn't work and I have above mentioned java doc as well.

```xml
<module name="JavadocType">
    <property name="allowMissingParamTags" value="true"/>
</module>
```

Comment: You know it's a Javadoc warning, right? It's saying you don't have Javadoc for T.

Comment: If you want to turn the allowMissingParamTags off then you need to use JavadocMethod module instead of JavadocType. Document: http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is telling you that you did not write the javadoc for the method type parameter:

```
/**
 * ...
 * @param <T> This is the type parameter
 * @param ....
 */
 public <T extends Object> T getExpectedValue(
        final HttpServletRequest request, final Class<T> expected)
```

the produced javadoc will include a section like the following in the header:

```
Type Parameters: 
    T - This is the type parameter
```

Comment: but you do not have line i suggest to add in my answer

Comment: Do I need to add your java doc additionally or replace a line that I have? Could you let me know which line is wrong?

Comment: you don't have wrong lines, it's in addition; it is the documentation of the method type parameter, which complements the doc of the arguments and the return (which you already have)

Comment: Your answer worked. Thank you. I just don't have enough point to mark yours as an answer. I will do that when I am able to. :)

Answer (score 3):

You add an `@param` tag for T to your Javadoc.

Something like this:

```
/**
 * ... other comments here ...
 * @param T The expected class of the value.
 * @param request ... other comments here ...
 * @param expected ... other comments here ...
 * @return ... other comments here ...
 */
public <T extends Object> T getExpectedValue(
    final HttpServletRequest request, final Class<T> expected)
```

If you *aren't* using Javadoc, then you probably shouldn't have Javadoc warnings enabled.

Comment: Could you check my java doc that I had?